# iOS accessing root of iCloud Drive with FileManager

Tags: ios, icloud-drive

I'm basically doing variations on this:

```
let dir = fileManager.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?
let files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: dir)
```

trying to get to the root (i.e., the "/") of iCloud Drive, where I have some files that aren't in any folder.

However, `dir` is (expectedly, I guess) my app's folder.

Is it even possible to access the root of iCloud Drive? I mean, users can obviously drop files here, but can I get to that directory? (Note that for the moment I'm trying to avoid using a `DocumentPickerViewController`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to access directly files outside of your app's iCloud container. I you want to allow users to give your app access to files that are potentially stored somewhere else, you need to `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

More information on iCloud documents can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForDocumentsIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH2-SW1

Comment: Ah. Figured that was the case but was holding out hope you could still access the non-app-specific root a la Dropbox or Google Drive or other cloud storage. Thanks.